# Python to Quickly Change 300K lines in a 8KK lines file

Tags: python, file, text

I am a chip test engineer, and I have one big text file about 8KK lines. For this file, most lines include '='. Meanwhile I have a log file, which is about 300K lines, each line is show a test failure. I need to change the 300K lines of the original file.
Currently it takes about 15 hours to finish the job.

[image: current time]

I have existing solution, but it is too slow.

For the code, the *parse_log* is used to process the log file and get to know each modification to be made, and the *stil_parse* include below function:

- read file as list in memory;
- iterate the file, and modify each line in list if included in log file;
- write back to disk;

```py
class MaskStil:
    def __init__(self):
        self.log_signal_file = ''
        self.pattern = r"^([^:]+)(:)(\d+)(\s+)(\d+)(\s+)(\d+)(\s+)(\d+)(\s)([.LH]+)$"
        self.log_signal = {}
        self.log_lines = []
        self.mask_dict = {}
        self.stil_name_new = ''
        self.stil_name = ''
        self.signal_all = {}
        self.signal_group = []
        self.offset = 0
        self.mask_mode = -1  # mask_mode 0: revert between L/H; mask_mode 1: mask L/H to Z
        self.convert_value=[{"L":"H", "H":"L"}, {"L":"Z", "H":"Z"}]
        for i in range(100):
            self.log_signal[i] = ''

    def digest(self, log_signal, stil_file, signal_group, offset, mask_mode = 1):
        self.log_signal_file = log_signal
        self.stil_name = stil_file
        self.stil_name_new = stil_file[:-5] + '_mask.stil'
        self.signal_group = signal_group.replace('=', '+').strip().split('+')
        self.offset = offset
        self.mask_mode = mask_mode
        for i in range(1, len(self.signal_group)):
            self.signal_all[self.signal_group[i]] = (i - 1) / 10 + i
        print(self.signal_all)
        self.parse_log()
        self.stil_parse()

    def parse_log(self):
        with open(self.log_signal_file) as infile:
            line_num = 0
            blank_line = 0
            for line in infile:
                line_num += 1
                if line_num == 1:
                    blank_line = line.count(' ')
                if "------------------" in line:
                    break
                for i in range(blank_line, len(line)):
                    self.log_signal[i - blank_line] += line[i]
        for (key, value) in self.log_signal.items():
            self.log_signal[key] = value.rstrip()
        print(self.log_signal)
        with open(self.log_signal_file) as log_in:
            self.log_lines = log_in.read().splitlines()
        for line in self.log_lines:
            if re.match(self.pattern, line):
                match = re.match(self.pattern, line)
                cycle = int(match.group(9))
                signals = match.group(11)
                # print cycle,signals
                self.mask_dict[cycle] = {}
                for i in range(len(signals)):
                    if signals[i] != '.':
                        self.mask_dict[cycle][i] = signals[i]

    def stil_parse(self):

        cycle_keys = []
        vector_num = 0
        for i in self.mask_dict.keys():
            cycle_keys.append(i)
        with open(self.stil_name, 'r') as stil_in:
            stil_in_list = stil_in.read().splitlines()
        total_len = len(stil_in_list)
        vector_cycle_dict = {}
        with tqdm(total=total_len, ncols=100, desc= " Stil Scanning in RAM Progress") as pbar:
            for i_iter in range(total_len):
                line = stil_in_list[i_iter]
                pbar.update(1)        
                if "=" in line:
                    vector_num +=1
                    if (vector_num in cycle_keys):
                        vector_cycle_dict[vector_num] = i_iter


                        status = line[line.find("=") + 1:line.find(";")]
                        # if cycle + self.offset in cycle_keys:
                        if vector_num in cycle_keys:
                            match = 1
                            for (i, j) in self.mask_dict[vector_num].iteritems():
                                mask_point = i

                                mask_signal = self.log_signal[i]
                                mask_value = j
                                test_point = self.signal_all[mask_signal]
                                test_value = status[test_point]
                                if test_value != mask_value:
                                    print("data did not match for cycle: ", test_value, " VS ", line, j, vector_num, mask_point, mask_signal, test_point, test_value)
                                    match = 0
                                    raise NameError
                                else:

                                    status = status[:test_point] + self.convert_value[self.mask_mode][test_value] + status[test_point + 1:]
                            if match == 1:
                                replace_line = line[:line.find("=") + 1] + status + line[line.find(";"):]
                            print("data change from :", line)
                            print("               to:", replace_line)
                            stil_in_list[i_iter] = replace_line
                        else:
                            print("No matching for %d with %s" %(vector_num, line))
                            raise NameError

        with tqdm(total=len(stil_in_list), ncols=100, desc= " Masked-stil to in RAM Progress") as pbar:
            with open(self.stil_name_new, 'w') as stil_out:
                for new_line in range(len(stil_in_list)):
                    pbar.update(1)
                    stil_out.write(new_line)
```

I was expecting a solution that could finish in about 1 or 2 hours.

Comment: I like to explicitly compile my Python regular expressions, then use the compiled re objects directly.  Python may cache the most recently used ones to avoid re-compiling, but I always like to make it explicit.  That way there's no guessing.  If nothing else, it saves a dynamic lookup.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, maybe a good try. But here the most time consuming is stil_parser, and regular expression is only used in the other function. Currently I am thinking whether there is a faster way to index, and modify.

Comment: Seems like multiprocessing or multithreading would give you a decent speedup here. Also, seeing as your log file is pretty huge, you may want to consider using `readline` instead of `read().splitlines.` That way you only pop one line into memory at a time. I imagine that may be one of your biggest drawbacks at the moment

Comment: Note that standard UNIX filesystem semantics only let you do an in-place replace if the new content is the exact same size as what it replaces (or smaller, and you pad with NULs, and your reader knows to ignore those NULs; a terminal will, but that's not true of everything). There are some platforms that have nonstandard extensions, but even when those exists, they generally allow content to be inserted or deleted at multiples of page (or block) size and along page (or block) boundaries.

Comment: if you could add a few lines from each file (or make up some lines that match the format) then you'll probably get more helpful responses as it makes it much easier to see what your code is doing when we can run it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to optimized the solution, and the timing consumed tremendously reduced to about 1 minute.

[image]

Mainly the optimization is in below fields:

1. instead of keeping checking `if (vector_num in cycle_keys):`, I use
   ordered list and always check whether equal to `index_to_mask`;
2. use variable `line_find_equal` and `line_find_coma` for further usage

```py
class MaskStil:
    def __init__(self):
        self.log_signal_file = ''
        self.pattern = r"^([^:]+)(:)(\d+)(\s+)(\d+)(\s+)(\d+)(\s+)(\d+)(\s)([.LH]+)$"
        self.log_signal = {}
        self.log_lines = []
        self.mask_dict = {}
        self.stil_name_new = ''
        self.stil_name = ''
        self.signal_all = {}
        self.signal_group = []
        self.offset = 0
        self.mask_mode = -1  # mask_mode 0: revert between L/H; mask_mode 1: mask L/H to Z
        self.convert_value=[{"L":"H", "H":"L"}, {"L":"Z", "H":"Z"}]
        for i in range(100):
            self.log_signal[i] = ''

    def digest(self, log_signal, stil_file, signal_group, offset, mask_mode = 1):
        self.log_signal_file = log_signal
        self.stil_name = stil_file
        self.stil_name_new = stil_file[:-5] + '_mask.stil'
        self.signal_group = signal_group.replace('=', '+').strip().split('+')
        self.offset = offset
        self.mask_mode = mask_mode
        for i in range(1, len(self.signal_group)):
            self.signal_all[self.signal_group[i]] = int(math.floor((i - 1) / 10) + i)
        print(self.signal_all)
        self.parse_log()
        self.stil_parse()

    def parse_log(self):
        with open(self.log_signal_file) as infile:
            line_num = 0
            blank_line = 0
            for line in infile:
                line_num += 1
                if line_num == 1:
                    blank_line = line.count(' ')
                if "------------------" in line:
                    break
                for i in range(blank_line, len(line)):
                    self.log_signal[i - blank_line] += line[i]
        for (key, value) in self.log_signal.items():
            self.log_signal[key] = value.rstrip()
        print(self.log_signal)
        with open(self.log_signal_file) as log_in:
            self.log_lines = log_in.read().splitlines()
        for line in self.log_lines:
            if re.match(self.pattern, line):
                match = re.match(self.pattern, line)
                cycle = int(match.group(9))
                signals = match.group(11)
                # print cycle,signals
                self.mask_dict[cycle] = {}
                for i in range(len(signals)):
                    if signals[i] != '.':
                        self.mask_dict[cycle][i] = signals[i]

    def stil_parse(self):

        cycle_keys = []
        vector_num = 0
        for i in self.mask_dict.keys():
            cycle_keys.append(i)
        with open(self.stil_name, 'r') as stil_in:
            stil_in_list = stil_in.read().splitlines()
        total_len = len(stil_in_list)
        index_to_mask = 0
        with tqdm(total=total_len, ncols=100, desc= " Stil Scanning in RAM Progress") as pbar:
            for i_iter in range(total_len):
                line = stil_in_list[i_iter]
                pbar.update(1)
                if "=" in line:
                    vector_num +=1
                    if (vector_num<=cycle_keys[-1]):
                        if (vector_num == cycle_keys[index_to_mask]):
                            line_find_equal = line.find("=")
                            line_find_coma = line.find(";")
                            status = line[line_find_equal + 1:line_find_coma]
                            # if cycle + self.offset in cycle_keys:
                            try:
                                match = 1
                                for (i, j) in self.mask_dict[vector_num].items():
                                    mask_point = i

                                    mask_signal = self.log_signal[i]
                                    mask_value = j
                                    test_point = self.signal_all[mask_signal]
                                    test_value = status[test_point]
                                    if test_value != mask_value:
                                        print("data did not match for cycle: ", test_value, " VS ", line, j, vector_num, mask_point, mask_signal, test_point, test_value)
                                        match = 0
                                        raise NameError
                                    else:
                                        status = status[:test_point] + self.convert_value[self.mask_mode][test_value] + status[test_point + 1:]
                                stil_in_list[i_iter] = line[:line_find_equal + 1] + status + line[line_find_coma:]
                                # print("data change from :", line)
                                # print("               to:", stil_in_list[i_iter])
                                index_to_mask = index_to_mask+1
                            except (Exception) as e:
                                print("No matching for %d with %s" %(vector_num, line))
                                raise NameError

        with tqdm(total=len(stil_in_list), ncols=100, desc= " Masked-stil to disk Progress") as pbar:
            with open(self.stil_name_new, 'w') as stil_out:
                for i_iter in range(len(stil_in_list)):
                    pbar.update(1)
                    stil_out.write(stil_in_list[i_iter]+ "\n")
```

Comment: Something is fishy. 1 should give you a big speedup. 2 should give you a little speed up. I don't think either should give you a 99.8% reduction...

Comment: Also, I think you can replace the whole cycle_keys usage with just `if mask_dict.get(vector_num):`  #This will return true if there is an entry that matches vector_num

Comment: On second check, yeah, that for loop was likely the only problem. You saved yourself 150k checks per line that contains "="

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments, you can get some speedup by refactoring your code to be multithreaded or multiprocess.

I imagine you're also running into memory swapping issues here. If that's the case, this should help:

```py
with open(self.log_signal_file) as log_in:
    line = log_in.readline() # First line. Need logic to handle empty logs
    while line: #Will return false at EOF
        if re.match(self.pattern, line):
            match = re.match(self.pattern, line)
            cycle = int(match.group(9))
            signals = match.group(11)
            # print cycle,signals
            self.mask_dict[cycle] = {}
            for i in range(len(signals)):
                if signals[i] != '.':
                    self.mask_dict[cycle][i] = signals[i]
        line = log_in.readline()
```

Here we only read in one line at a time, so you don't have to try to hold 8KK lines in memory

---

*In case anyone else didn't know, KK means million apparently.

Comment: thanks for commenting, I found that python's iteration is pretty fast, and the real  bottleneck is actually repeated iteration and inquiring. As for multiprocess, it seems difficult to split a single big file into multi parts when we actually need to modify random 300K lines of it.